# Require CSS file from remote Server

Tags: php, css

I'm new to PHP an would like to require a CSS file from a Webserver.

I have `require "http://dev.zcktn.de/Web/CSS/Frameworks/RHWF/RHWF.css";` which returns `Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'http://dev.zcktn.de/Web/CSS/Frameworks/RHWF/RHWF.css' (include_path='[...]') in [...]/index.php on line 11` (line 11 is the line posted before).

How do I get the CSS into the PHP?

Thanks for any answer in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just put `<link REL="STYLESHEET" TYPE="text/css" HREF="http://dev.zcktn.de/Web/CSS/Frameworks/RHWF/RHWF.css">` in the HTML?

Comment: I guess because I'm kinda dumb... *facepalm*
Thanks mate